# How to escape chars in BSD tar path substitution option

Tags: bash, escaping, bsdtar

This does not work:

```sh
$ tar -cf /tmp/z.tar -C /space/myroot -s '/^\.svn\/patches/__patches' src .svn/patches
tar: Invalid regular expression: trailing backslash (\)
```

Also no good:

```sh
$ tar -cf /tmp/z.tar -C /space/myroot -s '/^\\.svn\\/patches/__patches' src .svn/patches
tar: Invalid replacement flag _
```

Every combination of backslashes (up to 4) and quoting gives me one of those two errors. However I know the first one works in sed:

```sh
$ tar -cf /tmp/z.tar -C /space/myroot src .svn/patches
$ tar -tf /tmp/z.tar | sed 's/^\.svn\/patches/__patches/'
src/a.c
src/b.c
__patches/A.patch
__patches/B.patch
```

Also I know I can cop-out and do this:

```sh
$ tar -cf /tmp/z.tar -C /space/myroot -s '/^.svn.patches/__patches' src .svn/patches
```

-- but I don't really want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [man bsdtar](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+5.3-stable):

> -s    pattern
>   ....
>   where old is a basic regular expression
>   ...

[Basic regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) should work with `\/`. Sadly `bsdtar` is incorrectly written here, and does not handle escaping correctly.

From [bsdtar/subst.c](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/master/tar/subst.c#L97):

```
end_pattern = strchr(rule_text + 1, *rule_text);
```

`rule_text` is a string `char *` which is passed with the string you pass to `-s` option, so it has the string `/^\.svn\/patches/__patches`. The `end_pattern` should point to the last character of the pattern (ie. to the `/` in from of `/__patches`). However as simple strchr is used, so the first `/` found is used (the character in `\/`), escaped or not, it is used. The error:

```
tar: Invalid regular expression: trailing backslash (\)
```

comes from [regcomp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp) trying to parse the regular expression `^\.svn\` (as this is the part stripped between the two `/`). As there is nothing behind the trailing backslash `\` in the expression, it throws an error (and is correct - a trailing backslash is there). One could think of posting a bug report to bsdtar developers, but it's probably not really worth fixing.

Note that the syntax for `-s` is `/old/new/`. There is a trailing `/` in the pattern, which you are missing. After the last `/` you can specify flags.

You can however workaround the issue with:

```
bsdtar -s '#\.svn/patches#__patches#'
```

Any character will work for the `/`.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think to try alternate delimiters since the man page for tar did not mention it. Also the missing delimiters in my question was just a cut/paste error.

Comment: This is why as much as I like to say to beginners that StackOverflow isn't as good as they think it is because of easily abusable mindless copy-pastery (and sometimes also why that is bad, as some don't have the experience to understand that), I don't allow me to state plainly that they shouldn't use it, as there is still plenty of useful gems like this. This info would take me ages to find out.